# Why does my User Defaults bool not set on first launch of app?

Tags: ios, swift, userdefaults

I have a `UserDefault` `Bool` for music playing.

When launched for the first time, I attempt to set the bool to true, like this...

```
if launchedBefore {

        // Do nothing.

    } else {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "musicOn")
        print("music is \(musicOn)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadylaunched")

    }
```

This is in `viewDidAppear()`.

The problem is that it does not set as true on the first launch, regardless of where I set the bool, it could be without the `launchedBefore` check, it still does not set on the first time.

I don't see why this wouldn't work? musicOn is equal to false always on first launch, then on second launch, it is true?

Any insight would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You are using the keys "musicOn" and "alreadylaunched", as far as I understand Userdefaults is case-sensitive. Are you looking at the right keys?

Comment: Hey Leo! Double checked my keys, they were all the same, but I did change them all to lower case, but that didn't work. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Can you show the code where you set `launchedBefore` ?

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is allowing var musicOn to equal to user default bool once again.

```
if launchedBefore {

        // Do nothing.

    } else {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "musicon")
        print("music is \(UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "musicon"))")

        musicOn = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "musicon") // Stating it again works to update the bool.

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadylaunched")

    }
```

Var musicOn was already instantiated outside of any functions, it seems it just needs to be set again.

Thanks you for your comments!

Comment: Why would you expect the act of setting a value in user defaults to affect a variable?

Comment: I thought that since the variable was equal to the user default and that it was updated early in viewDidAppear(), I assumed by the time it was used, the value would have been updated. Rookie error!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the method like this

```
let launchedBefore = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "alreadylaunched")
        if launchedBefore {

        // Do nothing.

    } else {

        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "musicOn")
     //   print("music is \(musicOn)")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "alreadylaunched")

    }
```